# Is there an alternate TLS implementaion to SChannel in .Net

Tags: c#, ssl, postman, tls1.2, schannel

I am trying to setup a 2-Way SSL with PEM certificate key pair on windows using .Net SSLstream. However I keep getting the followinng SChannel error: "A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10013.". The SSL handshake always fails. However when I use postman with the same certificate & key, it works fine. Does anyone know what postman uses internally? OpenSSL, boringSSL etc? Is there any alternate TLS implementation I can use in .Net?

Please refer this post for what I have tried : [SSL Handshake fails in C# but works in postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67731893/ssl-handshake-fails-in-c-sharp-but-works-in-postman)